# Dynamically annotate HTML?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, annotations

I would like to do the following in an ASP.NET page, for both Internet Explorer and Firefox:

1. Display an uploaded HTML document in a window.
2. Allow the user to highlight an arbitrary section with the standard text cursor, and press a "leave comment here" button.
3. Save the exact start and end points of the highlight -- not just the highlight contents -- and associate them with a unique ID.
4. Highlight everything between the start and end points by overlaying a <span class="highlight"> tag.

1 and 2 are no problem.  But for 3 and 4... is this possible?  If so, how can I go about this?

If this can't be done for an HTML document, how about plain text?  (For HTML, we can assume it is relatively simple.  For instance, I envision this supporting word documents saved as HTML.)

Comment: Sounds ambitious. Wrapping the start/end points around the proper node nesting in the parent document will be a nightmare, especially with the notoriously redundant HTML coding Word puts in place. EEK!

Comment: Did you just call "Word documents saved as HTML" simple?

Comment: Heh, okay, I take it back.  But I was thinking simple in the sense that these are documents verses full-fledged professional web sites.

Answer (score 6):

Well you have a problem.

Suppose this text:

```
Hello my
name is
Josh and
this is an
example for you
```

Which underneath was like this:

```
<span>
  Hello my
  <span>
    name is<br/>
    Josh and
  </span>
  <span>
    this is an<br/>
    example for you
  </span>
</span>
```

Then suppose I select:

```
Josh and
this is an
```

The HTML I've selected is:

```
  Josh and
</span>
<span>
  this is an
```

So if you wrap a span around that, you'll end up with some screwed up HTML.

So, I would recommend the following:

- Get the selected text with javascript
- Strip the HTML tags from the selected text

You end up with this:

```
function getSelectedTextNoHtml() {
    return getSelectedText().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
}

function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection)
        return window.getSelection();
    else if (document.getSelection)
        return document.getSelection();
    else if (document.selection)
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    return "";
}
```

You could then take the HTML of the whole document, strip the HTML tags and find the index of the selected text within the text version of the document.

I can even think of (ugly but workable) ways of getting the index of the selection in HTML. But I warn you if you want them they're ugly.

There are *even* very ugly ways to get a span neatly around the selected text with the unique ID you want. Of course there's always ways to do stuff. Everything is just an algorithm away. But it would involve a good days work honing it down!

I've posted enough, if you want me to elaborate, just ask!

**UPDATE:**

OK, you asked for it :)

- Take the selected text and log it somewhere
- Replace the selected text temporarily with something utterly unique
- Find the index of that utterly unique text
- Change the text back

If you want to do it discreetly without their text flashing and changing, you could try taking advantage of the HTML zero-width space:

```
&#8203;
```

Stick that in front of it 100 times and find the index of 100 zero width spaces!

Of course, it will fail if their document has 100 zero-width spaces *and* their selected text elsewhere, but at this point I say "let it fail" :)

Howzat?

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The solution of stripping the HTML tags and finding the index of the selected text would work fine unless the user highlights text that's duplicated in the document. So, at the risk of delving into ugliness...  is there a way to get an index of the selection from javascript?  (Suppose it's just a plain text document... although that would obviously be contained in an HTML page...)

Comment: This still doesn't cover finding the index in the HTML document, but that is possible too.

But bed calls me, so I shall attend further tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks for the help--great idea with the swapping.  When I get to this feature I'll be sure to try it out.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @cweiske's list, there is also Annotator:

- https://github.com/edsu/annotator-okfn

Answer (score 1):

There are several HTML annotation tools available:

- http://code.google.com/p/adnotatio/
- http://code.softwarefreedom.org/projects/stet
- http://code.google.com/p/adnotatio/wiki/References